# How was Noah able to distinguish between clean and unclean animals even before the Law was given?

Tags: genesis, law, noah

> Genesis 7:2 (NKJV)
>
> "You shall take with you seven each of every **clean
>   animal,** a male and his female; two each of animals that are unclean, a
>   male and his female
>
> Genesis 8:20 (NKJV)
>
> Then Noah built an altar to the LORD, and took of **every clean animal
>   and of every clean bird**, and offered burnt offerings on the altar.

According to these passages, Noah knew about **clean animals and clean birds.**

How did Noah know this even before the Law was given?

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ  This is not a duplicate question. I'm asking not asking about the meaning of clean and unclean birds. I'm asking about Noah.

Comment: If Noah was righteous, I'm looking for insight into his righteousness through this scripture.

Comment: While worded differently, your question is the same as the one I linked to. The currently accepted answer directly answers your "how did Noah know this?" question. But it takes 5 votes to close a question, so yours may very well remain open if 4 others don't vote to close it too.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ But there was only one answer to that question. And that is not an answer to this question. That is not an answer that I will accept.  So I deserve a right to alternative view points.

Comment: There are 2 answers to that question. If you are not satisfied with the answers for any particular question, you can always set a bounty on it and specify what additional things you are looking for. Additionally, if your question does end up being closed, it can still be reopened again if 5 reopen votes are cast.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to think that this distinction (along with many others) first appeared at the time of Moses. The Law-Giver revived Jewish customs (after they have been more-or-less weakened, corrupted, and/or abandoned due to Egyptian influence), expanded them (in a logical and self-consistent manner), strengthened them, systematized them, and enforced their observance, but he did not “randomly” amend the ancestral national traditions.

Comment: How did Adam know what a tree, garden or the word 'eat' meant? It has long been believed that the meaning of a Hebrew word is made up by the combined metaphor of the letters.  No one here likes that answer. And it just pushes the question: How did he know the metaphor of the letters? ..from the metaphor of the strokes. Yes. But how did he know them. It is obvious  that humans have the genetic ability to learn language.  We can trace the metaphor of the word to the strokes, so it might be suggested that the word itself gives clues to the meaning. Can't do it on one page. Invites too much grief.

Comment: @BobJones do you have any articles, blog or write-ups of any kind. I'll like to follow you in your thoughts about scripture.

Comment: 1st Ark had the animals of the first man/woman, perfect, in Gen. 1 - they went *all* 2x2.  Then we have the 2nd Ark of those who were born after the partaking of the 'tree of the knowledge of good and evil'. Because of the need for sacrifice to offset sin (and so there would always be clean animals available), the numbers had to be such that unclean animals didn't outweigh the clean ones. What would have happened if all the clean went extinct?